# Why are properties added to the String.prototype of one IFRAME not available in string objects created using the IFRAME's String function?

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe, prototype

I am working on a GWT project where the host page has scripts that add properties to `String.prototype`. The host page scripts rely on the existence of these properties in order to run correctly, so I need to make sure that whenever I pass a string from GWT to "host code", the extra properties are present in the object.

I thought that by calling `$wnd.String` in a non-constructor context, the extra properties would be there, but this appears to not be the case. In this mock-GWT setup, for example:

`test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

String.prototype.myStartsWith = function String_myStartsWith(prefix) {
    prefix = String(prefix);
    return (this.indexOf(prefix) === 0);
};

function onLoad() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.src = "javascript:''";
    iframe.id = "myFrame";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.location.replace("myFrame.html");
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```

`myFrame.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><script>

var $wnd = parent;
var $doc = $wnd.document;

debugger;

</script></head></html>
```

When execution hits the `debugger` line, the following results are obtained using the JS debugger console:

```
> $wnd.String !== String
true

> new $wnd.String("test").myStartsWith === undefined
false

> $wnd.String.prototype.myStartsWith === undefined
false

> $wnd.String("test").myStartsWith === undefined
true
```

The results are the same in Firefox 18.0, Safari 6.0.2, and Opera 12.12.

The first three are expected, but I did not expect the fourth check, `$wnd.String("test").myStartsWith === undefined`, to be `true`.

Why is it that `myStartsWith` is not available in string objects returned by calling `$wnd.String` in a non-constructor context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it that `myStartsWith` is not available in string objects returned by calling `$wnd.String` in a non-constructor context?

Because the [non-constructor String function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.1) just applies [`ToString`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8) and returns a *primitive* string value. If you access a property of that, the String constructor of the *current* global context is used - the one without a modified prototype. So

```
$wnd.String("test").myStartsWith
```

is evaluated to

```
"test".myStartsWith
```

and is equivalent to

```
new String($wnd.String("test")).myStartsWith
```

which is `undefined` of course.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an answer (not sure how gwt works)

you are changing the prototype on a different Window

then:

```
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.id = "myFrame";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.onload = function(){

         // here is the correct prototype
         this.contentWindow.String.prototype.myStartsWith =
                    function(){ alert("hello"); };

    }
    iframe.src = "myFrame.html";
```